# CiviCRM upgrade `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity error

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, database, mariadb

Upgrading a CiviCRM DB from 4.7.17 to 4.7.29 after moving from MySQL 5.1 (CentOS 6 install) to CentOS 7 with MariaDB 10.2.  After the progress bar completes on the wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1 page, then I get an error:

```
backTrace

#0 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(984): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...")
#3 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, (Array:2), "ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...")
#4 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -2, 16, (Array:2), "ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, "ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...", "1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...")
#7 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...")
#9 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446): DB_common->query("ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...")
#10 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635): DB_DataObject->_query("ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...")
#11 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(369): DB_DataObject->query("ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...")
#12 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1318): CRM_Core_DAO->query("ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...", FALSE)
#13 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Logging/Schema.php(399): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NU...", (Array:0), TRUE, NULL, FALSE, FALSE)
#14 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Logging/Schema.php(468): CRM_Logging_Schema->fixSchemaDifferencesFor("civicrm_activity", (Array:3), FALSE)
#15 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Logging/Schema.php(286): CRM_Logging_Schema->fixSchemaDifferencesForAll()
#16 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php(770): CRM_Logging_Schema->fixSchemaDifferences()
#17 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(182): CRM_Upgrade_Form::doFinish()
#18 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(81): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->runFinish()
#19 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->run((Array:2), NULL)
#20 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#21 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#22 /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1216): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#23 /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#24 /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#25 /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#26 /var/www/html/wp/wp-admin/admin.php(224): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#27 {main}




Database Error Code: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '() ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'When was the activity (or closely rela' at line 1, 1064
Additional Details:

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -2
    [message] => DB Error: syntax error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NULL () ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'When was the activity (or closely related entity) was created or modified or deleted.' [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '() ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'When was the activity (or closely rela' at line 1]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NULL () ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'When was the activity (or closely related entity) was created or modified or deleted.' [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '() ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'When was the activity (or closely rela' at line 1]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NULL () ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'When was the activity (or closely related entity) was created or modified or deleted.' [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '() ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'When was the activity (or closely rela' at line 1]"]
)
```

If I remove the () from the middle of the SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NULL () ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'When was the activity (or closely related entity) was created or modified or deleted.'
And do:
ALTER TABLE `civicrm`.log_civicrm_activity ADD   `modified_date` timestamp NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'When was the activity (or closely related entity) was created or modified or deleted.'
It adds to the DB.  However, a subsequent run of the upgrade process then tries to Modify the column and ends in essentially the same error at the same spot.  Anyone else run into this?  Is this a bug or problem with my install?

CentOS 7, CiviCRM 4.7.17->4.7.29, WordPress 4.9.2, MariaDB 10.2 SCL, PHP 7.0 SCL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran into this issue as well. Initially I wasn't sure if it was because I use multi-lingual (which adds some complexity) or because of MariaDB 10.2.

I had initially patched my version of CiviCRM to remove those empty `()`:

```
diff --git a/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Logging/Schema.php b/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Logging/Schema.php
index b3480601..e3a5d285 100644
--- a/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Logging/Schema.php
+++ b/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Logging/Schema.php
@@ -489,6 +489,7 @@ AND    (TABLE_NAME LIKE 'log_civicrm_%' $nonStandardTableNameString )
     $query = str_ireplace("DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", '', $query);
     $query = str_ireplace("DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", '', $query);
     $query = str_ireplace("NOT NULL", '', $query);
+    $query = str_ireplace('()', ' ', $query);
     return $query;
   }
```

However, looking at `civicrm_contact`, for example, I see `default current_timestamp()`, so the above replacements are causing the empty `()`.

It should probably something like this?

```
 $query = preg_replace("/DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(\(\))/", '', $query);
```

Comment: This is also somewhat relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722541/mariadb-current-timestamp-gets-changed-to-current-timestamp "All versions of MariaDB from 5.5 through 10.2 and all MySQL from 5.5 to 5.7 accept current_timestamp() syntax as default value for a timestamp column."

Comment: I'm also utilizing mulit-lingual.  I don't think current_timestamp() is the problem.  According to the docs current_timestamp and current_timestamp() are "symlinked" to Now().  However, your added line also changes NULL () ON UPDATE to NULL ON UPDATE.  That's where the problem seems to lie.  So from what I see it seems that your solution works, but not because of what you expected.  Why is there () after the NULL?

Comment: CiviCRM asks the database to output a table schema, in order to build the log table. If MariaDB outputs `modified_date timestamp NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` or `modified_date timestamp NULL DEFAULT  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, the `str_ireplace` from CiviCRM will convert it to: `modified_date timestamp NULL ()`. The code just didn't expect those parenthesis, so they are not removed. My initial patch focuses on the parenthesis, but a better patch would probably be to have a regexp conditionally looking for those parenthesis?

Comment: Ah!  Now I see.  So, it's simply leaving the () from the initial call.  I think what you suggest should work, or perhaps above the first shown line adding:  $query = str_ireplace("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP\(\)", 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', $query);

Comment: Both edits seems to work fine.  (After fixing the trailing slash.)  Adding another str_ireplace command keeps the code uniform in that section, but utilizing preg_replace decreases code length.